# Wrong wp-admin URL

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess, site-url

I freshly installed a WordPress site and I configured it behind a reverse proxy with site URL - `http://example.com/hello`

### Problem

I can reach the admin dashboard page, however I cannot go further as the link becomes `http://example.com/wp-admin` instead of `http://example.com/hello/wp-admin`. How could I get rid of this weird behaviour?

### Details that might help...

1. I am quite sure that the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are configured as `http://example.com/hello`, I even checked the database table `wp_options`.
2. When it arrives the admin dashboard page with correct CSS, the browser will show the correct link for half seconds and suddenly change to the wrong one. I even checked the network log in my Chrome and Firefox, the requested URL is `http://example.com/hello/wp-admin`.
3. I have tried to configure the `.htaccess` as well, but no luck.

   ```
   # BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /hello
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /hello/index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   # END WordPress
   ```

Comment: Possibly a plugin? Try disabling them http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-deactivate-all-plugins-when-not-able-to-access-wp-admin/

Comment: Possibly nope, it is a fresh and clean install with only 2 default plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, I found the reason of this weird behaviour.

It is caused by the JavaScript embedded in `wp_admin_canonical_url()` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_admin_canonical_url/)

The URL is determined by this piece of code

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

where the latter one returns `wp-admin` instead of `hello/wp-admin`.

By manipulating the value in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, I can successfully get the correct behaviour in admin dashboard. But I still hope for an elegant solution without touching WordPress code.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('set_url_scheme', 'hacky_uri_fix', 10, 2);
function hacky_uri_fix($url, $scheme) {
    if ( $url === {{BAD ADMIN URL}} ) {
        $url = {{CORRECT ADMIN URL}}
    }
    return $url
}
```

should work, just replace the bad URL you are trying to avoid with the correct one.  I'm sure there's a better solution to this out there but I'm not super familiar with subfolder installs and this should work without touching core code.

Answer (score -1):

Victor is 100%, so save the next person (maybe even myself) work digging further:

- the function wp_admin_canonical_url is in the ./wp-admin/includes/misc.php file
- Change

  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

to be

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/news/. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Where /news can be anything you have as a path in front of the wp-admin folder.

Comment: Please don't ever edit core files.  This is bad and will break if you update Wordpress (which you should be doing for security updates at the minimum)

Comment: Then what is the path forward? My whole site including all of the admin panels work great EXCEPT for the left hand panel. It cuts off the "/news" path. You can neg my answer and his find as well. but until something else "core" comes along and works this is a VALID. WORKING. work around.

Comment: Follow that function down the rabbit hole until you find a filter you can hook on to.  I think the hook you're looking for is gonna be `set_url_scheme`